# Modify nginx config file in Elasticbeanstalk to increase body size .platform / .ebextension folders not taking effect

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to upload large files to the server (some of them reach 1GB) and I get this error:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.20.0</center>
</body>

</html>
```

I know this error comes from ningx, and I need to increaste

> client_max_body_size

I created a .ebextensions folder with this structure:

> .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf

Also I created a .platform folder with the same structure

> .platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf

proxy.conf contains:

> client_max_body_size        999M;

After doing that and deploying it keeps throwing the same error.

The platform (created by elastic beanstalk) is

> Linux/UNIX

I can see in the logs (eb-engine.log) this, but Im not sure if it is because of what I did:

> 2022/09/22 11:00:35.780593 [INFO] Executing instruction: start proxy
> with new configuration 2022/09/22 11:00:35.780613 [INFO] Running
> command /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c
> /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf 2022/09/22 11:00:35.803451 [INFO]
> nginx: the configuration file /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf
> syntax is ok nginx: configuration file
> /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue. I was actually doing it okey, but I missed moving the .platform folder to the dist/ folder in the build step.
So I just did:

```
- cp -R .platform/ dist/.platform
```

in the postbuild step.

Comment: After spending days trying to figure this out, it turned out this was the step I missed as well. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `.platform`, not `.ebextensions`. For example:

**.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf**

```
client_max_body_size 999M;
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I tried with .platform also, I will update my question. However, I will double check.

Comment: Yeah, keeps saying the same..